# Python3 One string to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, post

I'am working on a project in python. I've got a webserver running that receives post data. I want to turn that data into sepparate variables so that I can do something else with it.

I've got this:

```
for item in (post_data.decode("utf-8").split('&')):
    print(item)
```

That returns this:

```
name=john
lastname=smith
```

but I want to set that as variables so I can do:

```
print(name)
```

and return John

Comment: How about creating a dictionary and doing `dict_name['name']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use two `.split()` functions and then create a *dictionary*. From here we can print `name` and `lastname`.

```
s = 'name=john lastname=smith'
dicta = (dict([i.split('=') for i in s.split()]))

print(dicta['name']) # => john
print(dicta['lastname']) # => smith
```

also using *dictionary comprehension*

```
dicta = {i.split('=')[0]: i.split('=')[1] for i in s.split()}
```

Comment: This worked for my, I had to change it up a bit to work with my postdata (var s)

Answer (score 0):

If the output is a single string: `'name=john lastname=smith'` you can use a list comp like

`[j.split('=')[1] for j in n.split()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression to split the strings with `=` and unpack the output to a tuple of variables:

```
name, lastname = (p.split('=', 1)[1] for p in post_data.decode("utf-8").split('&'))
```